# does using where clause on my indexed column to get range of data make query faster

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I have 200 million rows of date, where it is indexed in column named date.

I am trying to bring table into python using pymysql so I can analyze.

Does having where clause to get smaller chunk of data take longer than getting all the data?

Here is my query:

```
query = """
select 
  serial_number,
  k.date,
  battery_rate,
  controller_battery,
  mode
from table k
where k.date between date('2019-06-15') and date('2019-06-20');
"""
```

I would like to get whole table if possible but I'd thought since index is on date column I can use where clause to get range of data faster as mysql does not need to look at rows out of the range. Correct me if my hypothesis is wrong.

What is the most efficient way of getting data?

NOTE: cardinalty of date index is high however I cannot change it.

Comment: btw you don't need to put dates in a `date` function. They are understood when quoted in `YYYY-MM-DD` notation.

Comment: Note that date() is redundant

Answer (score 1):

If the cardinality on the `date` column be high, then your index on `date` should already be helping the query.  You may run `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` on your query to see what MySQL is actually choosing to do under the hood.  That being said, you could add the following index, which covers the entire `SELECT` clause:

```
CREATE INDEX cover_idx ON yourTable (date, serial_number, battery_rate,
    controller_battery, mode);
```

This index, if used by MySQL, would completely cover the entire query, meaning that no seek back to the clustered index (i.e. the original table) would be needed.

Comment: Creating index on a table with large number of rows takes a long time...

Comment: Well if your current index on `date` alone doesn't help...then it doesn't help.  I'm giving you another index suggestion which might perform a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have enough memory and you do not need records from different chunks the same time, you can simply use the formula:

time = constant * volume

and ignore the rest. Therefore if you need the whole data to process, it does not matter you split it or not and you even spend some extra time for split processing.

In other words, index works fast if you just need to get 200 records once or twice, but if you want to get 200 records million times, it does not matter you use index or select the whole table.

However this is in ideally working environment. In real environment 200 million record may bring some unexpected delays and even system issues, especially with mysql. So it might be a good idea to split it even though theoretically it takes the same time.

Just play with data, queries on your environment and see the difference.